# Reading command line arguments into a new array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, command-line-arguments

There's no way to know how many arguments there are; the user can provide a list of indeterminate length.

I'm very bad with C. How can I read arguments out of the command-line array and into a new array of strings?

Frankly I don't even know how to make an array of separate strings, if I'm going to be honest. An example would be super-helpful.

Comment: Can't say that I understand what you are asking for. Usually the first argument to `main` is an `int` that holds the number of commandline arguments.

Comment: Do you mean getting arguments out of the command line? These are passed to your `main()` function in the `argc` and `argv` parameters. The former is an integer containing the count of the arguments and the latter is an array of pointers to `char`s (i.e. strings).

Comment: Have you tried google("c command line arguments")?

Comment: Oh, I'm an airhead. Of course argc tells me how many they gave. I'm tired; don't judge me. So what I'm uncertain of is how to read a number of the array-parameter's contents into a different array. The first one (argv[1]) is for one thing, but everything else goes together and I'd like to group it into a new array somewhere else.

Comment: I can't imagine why, but someone might want to squirrel away these arguments as part of a log as to how the program was called. IMHO it's a good, albeit somewhat unique, question.

Comment: As an additional comment and just a suggestion, your post probably got voted down, because you didn't put up work to show what you had done. It goes a long way in this forum to show something you have tried before asking a question. Else, search for examples online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is.

If you look at the main function's full prototype:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
```

**argc**: This is the argument counter, it contains the number of argument given by the user (Assumin the command is `cd`, entering `cd home` will give argc = 2 because the command name is always argument 0)

**argv**: This is the arguments values, it is an array of size *argc* of `char*` pointing to the arguments themselves.

**env**: This is a table (as argv) containing the environment when the program is called (through a shell for example, it's given with `env` command).

As for **an example of making an array of *things*:** Two ways are possible:

First, a fixed-length array:

```
char tab[4]; // declares a variable "tab" which is an array of 4 chars
tab[0] = 'a'; // Sets the first char of tab to be the letter 'a'
```

Second, a variable-length array:

```
//You cannot do:
//int x = 4;
//char tab[x];
//Because the compiler cannot create arrays with variable sizes this way
//(If you want more info on this, look for heap and stack memory allocations
//You have to do:
int x = 4; //4 for example
char *tab;
tab = malloc(sizeof(*tab) * x); //or malloc(sizeof(char) * x); but I prefer *tab for
//many reasons, mainly because if you ever change the declaration from "char *tab"
//to "anything *tab", you won't have to peer through your code to change every malloc,
//secondly because you always write something = malloc(sizeof(*something) ...); so you
//have a good habit.
```

**Using the array:**

Any way you choose to declare it (fixed-size or variable-size), you always use an array the same way:

```
//Either you refer a specific piece:
tab[x] = y; //with x a number (or a variable containing a value inside your array boundaries; and y a value that can fit inside the type of tab[x] (or a variable of that type)
//Example:
int x = 42;
int tab[4]; // An array of 4 ints
tab[0] = 21; //direct value
tab[1] = x; //from a variable
tab[2] = tab[0]; //read from the array
tab[3] = tab[1] * tab[2]; //calculus...
//OR you can use the fact that array decays to pointers (and if you use a variable-size array, it's already a pointer anyway)
int y = 21;
int *varTab;
varTab = malloc(sizeof(*varTab) * 3); // An array of 3 ints
*varTab = y; //*varTab is equivalent to varTab[0]
varTab[1] = x; //Same as with int tab[4];
*(varTab + 2) = 3; //Equivalent to varTab[2];
//In fact the compiler interprets xxx[yyy] as *(xxx + yyy).
```

Star-ing a variable is called dereferencing. If you don't know how this works I highly suggest you take a look.

I hope this is explained well-enough. If you still have questions please comment and I'll edit this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

}
```

This is how you declare your main entry function. 
`argc` is the number of arguments input by the user INCLUDING the program name which is the first string in `argv` (`argv[0]` = program name).

and since argv is an already array of strings I suggest you use as this is what it is for. (Just don't forget to skip index 0)

Answer (score 0):

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

That's what main should look like in your program.  `argc` is the number of arguments passed into the program. `argv` is a list of strings which are the arguments passed into the program with argv[0] being the program name.